# python regex assistence

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want to test a file if it's valid with a regex.

`file_string = >sp|Q1ABCD|003R_FRG3G(438aa)Uncharacterizedprotein1A.[virus1(isolateABCD)(AB-1)]MLFLGTIGLAVVVGGLMAYGYYYGHHDE2-9:ArpllGKT>sp|Q2DBAC|004R_FRG3G(60aa)Uncharacterizedprotein1B.[virus2(isolateBGF)(AB-2)]NAKYDTDQGVGRMLFLGTIGLAVVVGGLMAYGYYYDGKTPSSGTSFHTASPSFSSRYRY33-40:GyyydGKT50-100:GyyydGKT>sp.......`
with the >sp.... I mean so on.

```
pattern = '^(>sp\\|[PQ].{5,7}\\|.+\\(\d+aa\\).*\\[.*\\][ACDEFGHIKLMNPQRSTVWY]*(\d+-\d+:.+)+)+$'
    import re
    ant = re.match(pattern,file_string)
```

But the regex I use matches always.  That's not correct.  How do I fix it?

Comment: "keeps saying" - keeps saying what? Also why `\\ ` before the `|`? You want to escape the pipe sign not the slashes?

Comment: "this structure" - which structure? please edit your question to be as clear as possible

Comment: Try [`^(>sp\|[PQ][^|]+\|.+?\(\d+aa\).*?\[.*?\][AC-IK-NP-TVWY]*\d+-\d+:.+)+$`](https://regex101.com/r/mY1uD0/2).

Comment: I am sorry for the haziness, you are right @Torxed, I want to escape the pipe

Comment: I didn't work @WiktorStribiżew, maybe because my bad explanation

Comment: The doubled backslash is actually correct when the input is a quoted string, but you probably want a raw (`r'...'`) string and Wiktor's regex.

Comment: I clarified my question @tripleee, I wil try your suggestion

Comment: Well, I understand the problem BUT there are no actual requirements in the question. We can only guess them. The solution is to replace all dot matching subpatterns to more restricting ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the regex you've supplied it's enough if the first part of the first entry and the last part of the last entry matches. Because, as Wiktor S pointed out, the `.*` parts *eat* **anything**.

Try restricting your regex like

```
^(>sp\|[PQ].{5,7}\|(?:.(?!>sp))+?\(\d+aa\)(?:.(?!>sp))*?\[[^\]]*?\][ACDEFGHIKLMNPQRSTVWY]*(?:\d+-\d+:(?:(?!>sp).)+)+)+$
```

I've done some guesswork here (like that you don't really *need* to capture the final, possibly repeating, part of each entry) so you might have to adapt it somewhat.

[See it in action at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qE2oU4/2).

Regards